# Can't login to guest account in ubuntu

Tags: login, fglrx

After installing fglrx drivers I cannot login to my Ubuntu (both Admin and Guest accounts)
But after removing `~/.Xauthority` file I can log in to my Admin account., But still can't login to my Guest account. (when I click on login (guest) ,I'm getting back to the login page)
What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you press *login*?

Comment: I'm getting back to the login page